# Adding Properties to JavaPlugin’s SourceSets, Gradle

Tags: gradle

We're trying to draft a custom Gradle plugin to work with our modeling language, [Umple](http://cruise.eecs.uottawa.ca/umple/). We want to make it as "ergonomic" as possible and allow for specifying properties at the "sourceSet" level.

For example,

```
sourceSets {
  main { 
    umple {
      foo = 'bar'
    }
  }
}

umple { // defaults
  foo = 'baz'
}
```

We have tried adding extensions to the source sets and tried to model the approach after how the Scala and Antlr plugins work. However, we can not figure out how to add extra properties to the sourceSet closure application. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I believe the closest to what you are looking for will be the AndroidSourceSet: https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidSourceSet.html

Answer (score 3):

```
// TODO: take inspiration from https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/tasks/GroovySourceSet.java
public interface UmpleSourceSet {
    SourceDirectorySet getUmple();
    UmpleSourceSet umple(Closure configureClosure);
    UmpleSourceSet umple(Action<? super SourceDirectorySet> configureAction);
    SourceDirectorySet getAllUmple();
}

// TODO: take inspiration from https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/DefaultGroovySourceSet.java
public class DefaultUmpleSourceSet implements UmpleSourceSet { ... }

// TODO: take inspiration from https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/89b1c11a160c5f597c6c1ca50f01cf57e43c8356/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/GroovyBasePlugin.java#L88
public class UmplePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    private final SourceDirectorySetFactory sourceDirectorySetFactory;

    @Inject
    public UmplePlugin(SourceDirectorySetFactory sourceDirectorySetFactory) {
        this.sourceDirectorySetFactory = sourceDirectorySetFactory;
    }

    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getConvention().getPlugin(JavaPluginConvention.class).getSourceSets().all(new Action<SourceSet>() {
            public void execute(SourceSet sourceSet) {
                DefaultUmpleSourceSet umpleSourceSet = new DefaultUmpleSourceSet(((DefaultSourceSet) sourceSet).getDisplayName(), sourceDirectorySetFactory);
                new DslObject(sourceSet).getConvention().getPlugins().put("umple", umpleSourceSet);

                umpleSourceSet.getUmple().srcDir("src/" + sourceSet.getName() + "/umple");
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: So, I follow how to add a "sourceSet" but adding other properties to that `sourceSet` seems impossible. Which is OK, I guess. We need to figure out another means to set properties _within_ the sourceSet. Given the example from OP, setting `foo='bar'` is the missing part thus far.

Comment: Change `umple(Action<? super SourceDirectorySet> configureAction)` to `umple(Action<MyCustomObject> configureAction)` and add `setFoo(...)` to `MyCustomObject`

Comment: Looking at this now. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

This sounds similar to `GroovySourceSet`. See [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=GroovySourceSet&type=) for the `GroovySourceSet` references in the gradle sources.

This looks like the interesting bit in [GroovyBasePlugin.java](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/89b1c11a160c5f597c6c1ca50f01cf57e43c8356/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/GroovyBasePlugin.java#L88):

```
private void configureSourceSetDefaults(final JavaBasePlugin javaBasePlugin) {
    project.getConvention().getPlugin(JavaPluginConvention.class).getSourceSets().all(new Action<SourceSet>() {
        public void execute(SourceSet sourceSet) {
            final DefaultGroovySourceSet groovySourceSet = new DefaultGroovySourceSet(((DefaultSourceSet) sourceSet).getDisplayName(), sourceDirectorySetFactory);
            new DslObject(sourceSet).getConvention().getPlugins().put("groovy", groovySourceSet);

            groovySourceSet.getGroovy().srcDir("src/" + sourceSet.getName() + "/groovy");
```

*** Edit ***

I think the magic resides in [DSLObject](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/plugins/DslObject.java) (eg: `new DslObject(sourceSet).getConvention().getPlugins().put(...)`)

> Provides a unified, typed, interface to an enhanced DSL object. This
>   is intended to be used with objects that have been decorated by the
>   class generator.

See the documentation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html#sec:groovy_source_set_properties)

> The Groovy plugin adds the following convention properties to each
>   source set in the project. You can use these properties in your build
>   script as though they were properties of the source set object.

Comment: This doesn't look like it quite gets there. How are the `DynamicProperties` read/set?

Comment: I believe that `getConvention().getPlugins().put("groovy", ...)` is adding all of the methods from `GroovySourceSet` to every `SourceSet`. See the comment on [GroovySourceSet](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/a77a4c7b26bea5713ddb2480f41e09e56d321915/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/tasks/GroovySourceSet.java) which says "defines the properties and methods added to a SourceSet by the org.gradle.api.plugins.GroovyPlugin"

Comment: Oh, I meant adding properties _inside_ the `groovy` closure in this context. So how can properties be added to a `sourceSet`

Comment: We are talking about the same thing!!!! All the methods from `GroovySourceSet` are dynamically added to `SourceSet`. You should create a `UmpleSourceSet` and add it the same way as `GroovySourceSet`